# Como ler strings do Console?

Tags: javascript, string, io

Estou tentando fazer um código que leia uma string do `Console` do navegador e atribua o valor da string no id `"txtTextoResposta"`.

Para deixar mais ilustrado, quero fazer semelhante ao *C#*, quando fazemos assim:

```
string x = Console.ReadLine();
```

Tentei com o `ReadLine()`, mas não funcionou:

```
var x = readline();
document.getElementById("txtTextoResposta").innerHTML = x;
```

Tentei também com o `Console.Log`, mas ele retorna um erro:

```
var x = console.log;
document.getElementById("txtTextoResposta").innerHTML = x;
```

Erro:

> function log() { [native code] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O browser não permite código JavaScript ler o conteúdo da consola. Provavelmente por questão de segurança. Resposta meio curta, mas não vejo caminho por aí, pelo menos no browser.

Comment: O que estou fazendo não é para um site. É meio que um código para colar no console e executa-lo ali mesmo. Neste caso também não funcionaria?

Comment: @Francisco podes colocar código para executar na página, mas não consegues ler linhas que tenham sido escritas na consola.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o `prompt`

```js
console.log(prompt('Input'))
```